# c++ program not giving desired output

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

disclaimer: i am in 8th grade in school and we are learning the ancient and dead TURBO c++ as our first programming language. I have written around 50 simpler programs so far. here is the most intresting on i am working on.
i was writing a program to find sum of n natural number using classes and trying to make it 'failsafe'.
i am not getting the desired result. i am getting no errors and warnings from the compiler.
i am learning programming to understand logic and think like a programmer. Please do not judge me for using Turbo C++ i cannot do anything about it. I promise once i grow up then i will learn RUST.

here is my code:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class summer
{
 int n,s;
 public:
 int get();
 void calc();
 void show();
 void define();
 };

int summer::get()
{
 cout<<"Enter a Natural Number: ";
 cin>>n;
 return n;
}

void summer::calc()
{
 for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
 {
  s=s+i;
 }
}

void summer::show()
{
 cout<<"Sum of all natural Numbers till "<<n<<" is "<<s;
}

void summer::define()
{
 cout<<"\n\nA natural Number is a non decimal and non fractional number greater than 0";
}

void main()
{
 clrscr();
 summer obj;
 int ch=obj.get();
 if(ch>0)
 {
  obj.calc();
  obj.show();
 }
 else
 {
  cout<<ch<<" is not a natural number";
  obj.define();
 }
 getch();
}
```

cannot copy paste the output screen. please understand.
i input 5 and get output as 7888

Comment: `conio.h` and `iostream.h` has been removed from modern C++

Comment: i am using turbo C++ which still uses iostream.h and conio.h Please bear with me.

Comment: A cheap and simple way to avoid many bugs is to never leave a variable uninitialized. Read about the constructor in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: On a side note: if you've written *50* simpler programs, I would suggest that you're moving too slow.

Comment: @throwawayy1230321 *I promise once i grow up then i will learn RUST.* -- Why not simply get a modern, up-to-date, totally free, C++ compiler?  You have g++, clang, Visual C++ Community, all free and just a download click away.

Comment: Why on earth are you using obsolete software that is older than you?

Comment: @Jabberwocky the OP wrote in the question that it is a class requirement. And many things older than you or me are good or useful. E.g. may C++ only be used by people of 36 years or older? But I would recommend testing the programs with another installed compiler or an online compiler with all warnings turned on.

Comment: @Sebastian, TurboC is really obsolete (from the early 90s) and nowadays there is absolutely no reason for using it. It doesn't correspond to any standard, it's full of bugs, and it really shouldn't be used anymore especially as there are modern and free alternatives.

Comment: @Sebastian I may be able to understand if the compiler's were expensive, and the school's budget was an issue, but the compilers today are not only up-to-date, (up to C++20 and beyond), they are totally free to use.   After a quarter-century, you would think that at least one teacher or administrator would simply install one of these compilers and have the students use it.  There is absolutely no excuse to be using Turbo C++ as a teaching tool.  Also, that program was made for Windows 3.1 or MSDOS.  At some point, that compiler will stop working on modern PC's.

Comment: I agree, but the OP probably won't be able to change that. The OP made clear to be aware that it is an ancient compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is that the data member `s` has not been **initialized** and you're using that uninitialized data member which leads to **undefined behavior**.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

##### Solution

Since you're using Turbo, you can solve the problem by adding a parameterized constructor that initializes both the data members `n` and `s` to `0` as shown below:

```
//other code here as before
class summer
{
     unsigned int n,s;//unsigned int used instead of int
     public:
         int get();
         void calc();
         void show();
         void define();
         //parameterized constructor
         summer(): n(0), s(0) //uses constructor initializer list
         {
             
         }
 };

//other code here as before
```

The output of the modified program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/zd-lF9_Is).

Some of the changes i made include:

1. Added a parameterized constructor to initialize data members `n` and `s` to `0` using **constructor initializer list**.
2. Made the data members `n` and `s` to be of type `unsigned int`.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the variable s to solve your issue. When you add i to s the value of the variable s is not 0 (you can see that using the debugger). So just use the following line to assign 0 to s:

```
void summer::calc()
{
    s = 0; // Assign 0 to s

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        s = s + i;
    }
}
```

But if you wish to properly initialize it, use a constructor as such:

```
class summer
{
    int n, s;
public:

    summer();

    int get();
    void calc();
    void show();
    void define();
};

summer::summer() : n(0), s(0) { }
```

Any of the above work :)